# What situation would be best to use a vector? in C++?

Tags: vector

What is a vector? Why would I use it rather anything else?

Comment: I think the question should be: When should you **not** use a vector? std::vector is your general purpose go-to container.

Comment: "*What is a vector?*" - any [decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should cover that.

Comment: for basic reference https://www.edureka.co/blog/vectors-in-cpp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a dynamically sized array.  Use it whenever you need an array of elements that are stored contiguously in memory but you do not know the array's size at compile-time, only at runtime.